# Getting user's uploaded photos filtered by time, Facebook graph api v2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

In my application, i am getting user's uploaded photos from Facebook. i also want to filter the result by time. i was achieving this using FQL multiquery:

```
 //FQL multiquery

 [query_uploaded_photos] => select  object_id, album_object_id, owner, caption, place_id, created, comment_info.comment_count, like_info.like_count  from photo where owner in (me()) AND (( created >=  1425031156 AND created <= 1426149034 ))  limit 50

 [ppl_tagged_in_uploaded_photos] => select object_id, subject from photo_tag where object_id in  (select object_id from #query_uploaded_photos)
```

I am migrating my code to graph api v2.2. for above request i have implemented bellow implementation:

```
 //Graph request

 me/photos/uploaded?album{id},id,from{id},name,created_time,place{id},comments{comment_count},likes,tags{id}
```

It gives me all tag, like, comment data for uploaded photos, I tried to add filter for time in above graph request.

```
 //Graph request with time filter

 me/photos?fields=uploaded.since(1425031156){album{id},id,from{id},name,created_time,place{id},comments{comment_count},likes,tags{id}}
```

By adding filter it does not give me like, comment ,tag data.

How do i get result simlar to that i was getting through FQL implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to change the title of your question, since it's main issue is that the is not returning the fields you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
me/photos?fields=album{id},id,from{id},name,created_time,place{id},comments{comment_count},likes,tags{id}&since=1425031156&type=uploaded
```

Note: I moved the uploaded.since(#) from the fields list into two separate parameters at the end of the query string:  since=# and type=uploaded